# Misaligned fancyhdr footer when using color

Tags: color, fancyhdr

Strangely, using `{\color{}}` in `\lfoot{}` is causing my footer parts to misalign.

This code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}

%%%
\lfoot{{\color{blue}Build}}
%%%

\cfoot{\textcolor{blue}{P.\thepage}}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\title{Yep.}

\begin{document} 
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{fancy}

    \section{Blarg}
\end{document}
```

Produces...

[image: misaligned]

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why, but messing around, changing the `\lfoot{}` line

from

`\lfoot{{\color{blue}Build}}`

to

`\lfoot{\textcolor{blue}{Build}}`

Produced the result,

[image: corrected]

Still I figured I would share the result.